# 'See all' link with custom CAML query

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, caml

With Sharepoint online (highlighted content) :
Using a working CAML Query with Rowlimit, I've lost the "see all" link that is showed by default when I display without the query.  As soon as I chose a custom query the "Afficher tout" (in french) is not there any more...  How can I tell sharepoint to show it back via options ?

[image]

Comment: I am currently doing some research on this issue, will let you know as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

To help you better, are you using **Highlighted Content web part**? If yes, according to my research and testing, unfortunately, the "See all" link will disappears when we add the custom CAML query. And there is currently no out-of-the-box feature to display it, it is default.

I suggest you can **propose a feedback** on this issue. Many features of our current products are designed and upgraded based on customers’ feedback. With requirements like this increase, the problem may well be released in the future. Thanks for your understanding.

feedback:
https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/

===================================

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: yes that's what I am using.  It looks like the Ascending = "False" part of the custom CAML query isn't working as expected :(

Comment: According to my research and testing , unfortunately, it is by default. I suggest you can propose a feedback on this issue. Thanks for your understanding and support.